# Looking for clarification about good practice of query execution inside a component in Blazor Web Server App

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I am just a beginner in Blazor so I like to know your opinion regarding my doubt, let's say I have a master page in blazor where I use a Component (A) for presenting me some forms and then this Component have another Component inside (B) for show me some table rows where I could have buttons for begin edit process of the items in the row and a save button for execute the command of validation and saving the data inside the database.
I would like to know what's the best practice in this example, should I put all the logic of executing query for save the edited/new row inside the component (B) ? Or should instead calling EventCallback and reach douwn the master page and execute there all the DB query ? Thank you everyone for any help you can provide me.

Comment: I would prefer put the logic in component B. Because components should be convenient to reuse and it is better not mixing up the parent and child logics  together.

Comment: @QiangFu thank you for your comments, so you would like to keep even the Update or Delete command on the component B ? Using an eventcallback to the Master Page ?